# How to select last modified date for set of observed fields for each unique objects of some type?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a problem to write a query. Please help me I am not a database specialist.

### My Goal is:

Select last modified date for some set of observed fields for each unique object of type ProjectA. I have available only AuditLog table which is audit trail table and contains all modifications made on all objects (the old and new values are not important so i removed them from the table). Based on that table I can find all modification dates on objects of type ProjectA.

### AuditLog table:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------+-----+
| object_id | object_class | created_date        | field         | id  |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------+-----+
| 1000      | ProjectA     | 2014-12-12 10:45:49 | text3         | 105 |
| 1000      | ProjectA     | 2014-12-11 12:45:19 | text3         | 104 |
| 1000      | ProjectA     | 2014-12-10 12:45:19 | listValue5    | 104 |
| 12000     | ProjectA     | 2014-12-09 20:44:27 | largeText6    | 103 |
| 12000     | ProjectA     | 2014-12-09 19:44:20 | largeText7    | 102 |
| 100       | ProjectB     | 2014-12-08 19:42:37 | otherBfield1  | 101 |
| 100       | ProjectB     | 2014-12-08 19:41:11 | otherBfield1  | 100 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------+-----+
```

### Test for one object_id:

For getting last modified date for one object (object_id = 1000) the query can looks like this:

```
select created_date, object_class, object_id from (
  select  * 
  from    AuditLog
  where   object_class = 'ProjectA' and object_id = 1000
  and     created_date >= sysdate-30 ---- This is just so we have more results
  and     field in ('text3', 'listValue5', 'largeText6', 'largeText7', 'largeText8', 'listValue9')
  order by created_date desc
  )
where ROWNUM = 1;
```

Result:

```
CREATEDDATE          OBJECTCLASS   OBJECTJDOID
-------------------  -----------   -----------
2014-12-12 10:45:49  ProjectA      1000
```

The result is ok. We can assume that latest created_date in audit log for particular object is our last modified date. So, thanks to **order by created_date desc** and **ROWNUM = 1** I have the unique result which is the newest created_date for object_id = 1000.

### Problem

I need more generic query. The problem is when I try to remove from the query the condition: **object_id = 1000**, because then we would get only one latest result from **all** objects. What I need is to know latest created_date for **each of them** of type ProjectA (so in my example it should be for object_id=1000 and for object_id=12000). Of course I cannot list these ID's in where condition because I do not know all of them existing in DB and the new ones which will be created in the future.

### Question:

Now I need to retrieve last modified date for all of objects of type 'ProjectA' not only for object_id = 1000 but also for object_id = 12000 in my example table. How to do it? How to select from AuditLog table the only one last modification date for each unique object of type 'ProjectA'?
Do we need to do some grouping and then find the newest created_date for that grouped objects? How to do it? Please help in creating such a sql query.

Expected result should be:

```
CREATEDDATE          OBJECTCLASS   OBJECTJDOID
-------------------  -----------   -----------
2014-12-12 10:45:49  ProjectA      1000
2014-12-09 20:44:27  ProjectA      12000
```

How to build generic SQL query which will return such a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  max(created_date), object_class, object_id
  from    AuditLog
  where   object_class = 'ProjectA'
  and     created_date >= sysdate-30 ---- This is just so we have more results
  and     field in ('text3', 'listValue5', 'largeText6', 'largeText7', 'largeText8', 'listValue9')
group by object_id, object_class
order by created_date desc
```

Answer (score 4):

So, in order by grab the latest date for an object_id, it's a fairly straightforward query:

```
select object_id, max(created_date) 
  from auditlog
 group by object_id;
```

And you get

```
object_id  max(created_date) 
---------- -------------------
1000       2014-12-12 10:45:49
12000      2014-12-09 20:44:27
100        2014-12-08 19:42:37
```

But if you want more information, like the id, that presents a small problem.

```
select object_id, id, max(created_date) 
  from auditlog
 group by object_id, id;

object_id  id   max(created_date)
---------  ---  -------------------
1000       104  2014-12-11 12:45:19
100        100  2014-12-08 19:41:11
12000      102  2014-12-09 19:44:20
1000       105  2014-12-12 10:45:49
12000      103  2014-12-09 20:44:27
100        101  2014-12-08 19:42:37
```

You get around that by nesting another query to the table to get the correct date:

```
select object_id, id, created_date
  from auditlog a
 where created_date = (select max(created_date)
                         from auditlog b
                        where a.object_id = b.object_id);

object_id  id   max(created_date)
---------  ---  -------------------
1000       105  2014-12-12 10:45:49
12000      103  2014-12-09 20:44:27
100        101  2014-12-08 19:42:37
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
select object_id, max(created_date) as last_modified
from AuditLog
group by object_id
```

It is probably recommended to add an appropriate index on object_id and created_date for better performance..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [`GROUP BY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/group-by-functions.html) clause on `object_class` and `object_id` with a [`MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d4aa/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE AuditLog
    ("object_id" int, "object_class" varchar2(8), "created_date" timestamp, "field" varchar2(12), "id" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO AuditLog ("object_id", "object_class", "created_date", "field", "id")
         VALUES (1000, 'ProjectA', '12-Dec-2014 10:45:49 AM', 'text3', 105)
    INTO AuditLog ("object_id", "object_class", "created_date", "field", "id")
         VALUES (1000, 'ProjectA', '11-Dec-2014 12:45:19 PM', 'text3', 104)
    INTO AuditLog ("object_id", "object_class", "created_date", "field", "id")
         VALUES (1000, 'ProjectA', '10-Dec-2014 12:45:19 PM', 'listValue5', 104)
    INTO AuditLog ("object_id", "object_class", "created_date", "field", "id")
         VALUES (12000, 'ProjectA', '09-Dec-2014 08:44:27 PM', 'largeText6', 103)
    INTO AuditLog ("object_id", "object_class", "created_date", "field", "id")
         VALUES (12000, 'ProjectA', '09-Dec-2014 07:44:20 PM', 'largeText7', 102)
    INTO AuditLog ("object_id", "object_class", "created_date", "field", "id")
         VALUES (100, 'ProjectB', '08-Dec-2014 07:42:37 PM', 'otherBfield1', 101)
    INTO AuditLog ("object_id", "object_class", "created_date", "field", "id")
         VALUES (100, 'ProjectB', '08-Dec-2014 07:41:11 PM', 'otherBfield1', 100)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select  max("created_date") as created_date, 
        "object_class", 
        "object_id"
from    AuditLog
where   "field" in ('text3', 'listValue5', 'largeText6', 'largeText7', 'largeText8', 'listValue9')
group by "object_class", "object_id"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d4aa/8/0)**:

```
|                    CREATED_DATE | OBJECT_CLASS | OBJECT_ID |
|---------------------------------|--------------|-----------|
| December, 12 2014 10:45:49+0000 |     ProjectA |      1000 |
| December, 09 2014 20:44:27+0000 |     ProjectA |     12000 |
```